# Implementing Quicksort for an array of strings in C - why am I getting SIGABRT error?

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers, quicksort

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-quick-sort/) to implement Quicksort in C, but it assumes an integer array to be sorted, while I'm trying to sort an array of strings, which is to my understanding an array of character arrays, or `char array[][]`.

This is my implementation in the end:

```
void quicksort(char array[100][100], int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
    int pivotIndex, index1, index2;
    char temp[100];

    if (firstIndex < lastIndex) {
        pivotIndex = firstIndex;
        index1 = firstIndex;
        index2 = lastIndex;

        //Sorting in Ascending order with quick sort
        while(index1 < index2)
        {
            while(strcmp(array[index1], array[pivotIndex]) <= 0 && index1 < lastIndex)
            {
                index1++;
            }
            while(strcmp(array[index2], array[pivotIndex]) > 0)
            {
                index2--;
            }

            if(index1<index2)
            {
                //Swapping opertation
                strcpy(temp, array[index1]);
                strcpy(array[index1], array[index2]);
                strcpy(array[index2], temp);
            }
        }

        //At the end of first iteration, swap pivot element with index2 element
        strcpy(temp, array[pivotIndex]);
-->     strcpy(array[pivotIndex], array[index2]);
        strcpy(array[index2], temp);

        //Recursive call for quick sort, with partiontioning
        quicksort(array, firstIndex, index2-1);
        quicksort(array, index2+1, lastIndex);
    }
}
```

And my `main()`:

```
int main() {
    int numStrings = 100, maxLen = 100;
    char strings[numStrings][maxLen];
    printf("Give me some strings, each on a new line, and write STOP to stop:\n");

    char input[100];
    scanf("%s", input);

    int iteration = 0;

    while (strcmp(input, "STOP") != 0) {
        strcpy(strings[iteration], input);

        iteration++;

        scanf("%s", input);
    }

    quicksort(strings, 0, iteration);

    int j;

    printf("Your sorted strings:\n");
    for (j = 0; j < iteration; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[j]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

But the line above indicated with an arrow keeps giving me SIGABRT errors. What's wrong in my code above that is causing this? I'm admittedly new to C, so if there's anything catastrophically stupid about my implementation please just say so.

Comment: `iterations` is the number of strings and it is passed as `lastIndex` which becomes `index2` and then a call `strcmp(array[index2], ...` out-of-bounds UB for non-nul terminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `quicksort(strings, 0, iteration);` which will try to access the element at `iteration` location for which there might be memory access violation. For array of size of `iteration`, `iteration-1` is the last element. Hence, you should pass `iteration-1` rather than `iteration`.

Also, keep a check of iteration as it might cross the bound.

In `strcpy(array[pivotIndex], array[index2]);` in `quicksort` function, pivotIndex and index2 might be same and it might cause some problem. See this question: strcpy(array[pivotIndex], array[index2]);